# How to query mongodb for its YEAR(created_at) and GROUPBY YEAR(created_at) using Laravel

Tags: laravel, mongodb

I want to query customer collection (mongodb) using Laravel and it should GROUPBY ('YEAR(created_at)') and with no.of records in each year

Comment: for eg: I want to convert mysql SELECT COUNT(*), YEAR(created_at) as date where created_at >$dt1 and created_at<=$dt2 GROUP BY YEAR(created_at) to MONGODB's statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment, added date range in query as well.

```
db.customer.aggregate(
  [
    {
        $match: {
          '$and': [
            {
              'created_at': {
                $gte: new Date('2018-01-01')
              }, 
              'created_at': {
                $lte: new Date('2019-12-31')
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }, {
        $group: {
          _id: {
            year: {
              $year: "$created_at"
            }
          }, 
          count: {
            $sum: 1
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  )
```

The output would be like

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": "2018"
    },
    "count": 12
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": "2019"
    },
    "count": 19
  }
]
```

Comment: Glad to know that it works for you, would be more glad if you accept my answer.